# python installations, directories and environments - good resource to understand the basics

Tags: python

newbie here. I'm using python (3) on my mac, and although I'm able to write some (basic) scripts, I realise I have lots of confusion around where python is stored, the famous usr/bin directory, where packages are saved, etc.

For example I had pip installed and working fine, but then I installed miniconda and all of a sudden pip was 'managed' (for lack of a better term) by conda, some of the packages I had installed couldn't be found anymore etc.

This highlights just how confused I am with all of this. Can you recommend a good resource that can explain how these things work together? Ideally something for beginners :)

Comment: ...not to mention the various Ipython etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest to see: https://www.python.org/doc/

Then I suggest to look: http://code.tutsplus.com/series/python-from-scratch--net-20566

Answer (score 0):

Python has a lot off stuff. The very basics you can learn on codecademy.com.

On python-course.org you have some more advanced topics.

If you want to learn something specific you should look on the official python documentation.

Overal I don't think you want to use anaconda. It is better to just install the modules with PiP unless you are only doing scientific stuff or so.